# Date picker abre sozinho quando altera input vizinho

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Bom dia, tenho o seguinte código:

```
var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setDate( maxDate.getDate() + 364);

$(".dtpBloqueio").datepicker( {
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: maxDate
});
```

quando é alterado um input select que está dentro da mesma  do que o input da data, se for o caso, é setado o maxDate como hoje.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <select name="datasLocalizaSv" id="listaDatasLocalizaSv"/>
        </td>   
        <td>
          <input id="dataComeco" name="dataComeco" class="dtpBloqueio"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(".dtpBloqueio").datepicker("change", { maxDate: new Date() } );
```

Só que toda vez que troco a informação no select o datapicker abre sozinho no primeiro input, só que ele abre em branco, como se tivesse utilizado o "refresh".

[image]

Como posso fazer com que o datepicker não abra sozinho quando altero algo do lado dele?

Comment: Não compreendo bem o seu problema. Pode dar uma olhada a este jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ox5ax7z/ e adaptar explicando como quer que funcione?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seu erro está justamente no código que altera a data. Procurei na documentação e não existe esta opção `change`, então acho que isto está gerando algum evento que é interpretado como um clique. Tente substituir este código por algo como isto:

```js
$( ".dtpBloqueio" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", new Date() );
```

Comment: Quando eu coloco esse código, da o seguinte erro:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver assim:

```
$( ".dtpBloqueio" ).datepicker('destroy');
```

e depois eu criei novamente o `datepicker`:

```
$(".dtpBloqueio").datepicker( {
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: new Date()
});
```